# FolderExists returning wrong value

Tags: asp.net, path, server, backslash

I'm trying to get the last modified date of a file that is on a different server than the one I have the website page on. The problem is that the path to that file is like \\something.com\foldername\file.xlsx. I read that you can't use Server.MapPath with a path that contains double slashes or backslashes. I tried to replace the double backslash with one, three or four backslashes but it's not working. This is my code until now:

```
<%
dim fs, f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.GetFile(Server.MapPath("\\something.com\foldername\file.xlsx")) 
Response.Write("The file was last modified on: <h1 id='dateTime'>")
Response.Write(f.DateLastModified)
Response.Write("</h1>")
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

If I copy the file in the directory that contains the code and replace that line with..

```
set f=fs.GetFile(Server.MapPath("file.xlsx"))
```

..it works, but I don't get it how I can make it work with the original file.

Does anyone know how what I can do to replace the double backslash so that the program will work? I get a blank page if I try to use the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not know the difference between a relative and absolute path.

Say you want to create a link on your site to download the xlsx, you create a link like this.

```
<a href="/foldername/file.xlsx">file.xlsx</a>
```

However the absolute path on the server is something like

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\something.com\foldername\file.xlsx
```

What `Server.MapPath` does is translate the relative path to the absoule path so that the file can be located in a normal file system. So you use it like you would a normal html link.

```
Server.MapPath("/foldername/file.xlsx")
```

So if you want to know the last modified date you now do this:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("/foldername/file.xlsx"));
Label1.Text = file.LastWriteTime.ToString();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the file is already located on something.com? It's not. Basically, my site is on somethingelse.com, so Server.MapPath("/foldername/file.xlsx") doesn't work because it looks for the file on something.com, yes?

Comment: You mean `something.com` is an actual website, not a folder name on your server. Then this won't work because you do not have access to the file system. The only way is downloading that file, store it on your own server and check the properties there.